# How to get device serial number when running Debian preseed installation?

Tags: debian, preseed

I know that you could extract serial number from machine running
`dmidecode -t system`, but how could I do that when running preseed installation of Debian? `dmidecode` command is not yet available, is it somehow possible to install/run it at the installation of the distro?

Comment: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs04.html.en#preseed-pkgsel This link offers details on installing individual packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your environment and precise needs:

- If you boot the installer via Syslinux, you can use `SYSAPPEND 0x80` to put it on the kernel command line.
- Or you can preseed `anna/choose_modules` to `dmidecode-udeb` to make it available in the installer environment.
- Or you can parse the serial number out of `/sys/firmware/dmi/entries/1-0/raw` (but that's binary).
- Or you can preseed `pkgsel/include` to install it into your target system and use it from there.

Comment: Thanks Ferenc, the `anna/choose_modules` sounds like a plan, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

By way of example, here's how I assign the product serial number to the hostname:

```
# preseed.cfg
d-i preseed/early_command string \
  debconf-set netcfg/get_hostname "$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial)"
d-i netcfg/get_hostname seen true
```

That's the relevant section of a `preseed.cfg` I use with my Ubuntu installers to get pertinent DMI things.

I did try to use `dmidecode` but...

- `anna/choose_modules string dmidecode-udeb` (apparently) failed to install the "microdeb" early enough
- `preseed/early_command string anna-install dmidecode-udeb` *also* failed to install it

`pkgsel/include string dmidecode` *did* install the package on the target, but only *after* the network configuration. I tried to use `preseed/late_command string in-target` to `sed -i "s/dummyhostname/$(dmidecode -s system-serial-number)/g"` files under `/etc/` but I kept finding the hostname in more places.